# Pandas groupby apply function that combines some groups but not others

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I'm using pandas `groupby` on my DataFrame `df` which has columns `type`, `subtype`, and 11 others. I'm then calling an `apply` with my `combine_function` (needs a better name) on the groups like:

```
    grouped = df('type')
    reduced = grouped.apply(combine_function)
```

where my `combine_function` checks if any element in the group contains any element with the given subtype, say 1, and looks like:

```
def combine_function(group):
    if 1 in group.subtype:
        return aggregate_function(group)
    else:
        return group
```

The `combine_function` then can call an `aggregate_function`, that calculates summary statistics, stores them in the first row, and then sets that row to be the group. It looks like:

```
def aggregate_function(group):
    first = group.first_valid_index()
    group.value1[group.index == first] = group.value1.mean()
    group.value2[group.index == first] = group.value2.max()
    group.value3[group.index == first] = group.value3.std()

    group = group[(group.index == first)]
    return group
```

I'm fairly sure this isn't the best way to do this, but it has been giving my the desired results, 99.9% of the time on thousands of DataFrames. However it sometimes throws an error that is somehow related to a group that I don't want to aggregate has exactly 2 rows:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13,), indices imply (13, 5)
```

where my an example groups had size:

```
In [4]: grouped.size()
Out[4]: 
type
1         9288
3         7667
5         7604
11           2
dtype: int64
```

It processed the 3 three fine, and then gave the error when it tried to combine everything. If I comment out the line `group = group[(group.index == first)]` so update but don't aggregate or call my `aggregate_function` on all groups its fine.

Does anyone know the proper way to be doing this kind of aggregation of some groups but not others?

Comment: Have you tried just using an apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `aggregate_functions` looks contorted to me. When you aggregate a group, it automatically reduces to one row; you don't need to do it manually. Maybe I am missing the point. (Are you doing something special with the index that I'm not understanding?) But a more normal usage would look like this:

```
agg_condition = lambda x: Series([1]).isin(x['subtype]').any()
agg_functions = {'value1': np.mean, 'value2': np.max, 'value3': np.std}

df1 = df.groupby('type').filter(agg_condition).groupby('type').agg(**agg_functions)
df2 = df.groupby('type').filter(~agg_condition)

result = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Note: `agg_condition` is messy because (1) built-in Python `in` refers to the *index* of a Series, not its values, and (2) the result has to be reduced to a scalar by `any()`.

Comment: This seems like what I should be doing. I played with it some yesterday but its still kicking a lot of errors for me. I think it has something to do with my handling of the other 8 columns where I just wanted to aggregate use the first value. I'm sure there is an easy fix, and I'll update once I have it working.